# Referencing code value tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have just started working with MySQL and have a quick question. I would like to create a table "My_Table" that has a field "SEX". I would also like to create a table "SEX_Values" which has fields "CODE" and "VALUE" with 0 = male, 1 = female. so that it looks like this.

```
  My_Table            SEX_Values
  +--------+          +--------+--------+ 
  |  SEX   |          |  CODE  |  VALUE |
  +--------+          +--------+--------+
  |        |          |   0    |  male  |
  +--------+          +--------+--------+
                      |   1    | female |
                      +--------+--------+
```

I would like to somehow put a constraint on the SEX field in My_Table so that the data that is inserted/imported into it must match one of the codes in the SEX_Values table and if it doesn't I would like to throw a warning, something like this.

```
  My_Table             SEX_Values
  +--------+           +--------+--------+ 
  |  SEX   |<reference>|  CODE  |  VALUE |
  +--------+           +--------+--------+
  |   1    |  >OK      |   0    |  male  |
  +--------+           +--------+--------+
  |   0    |  >OK      |   1    | female |
  +--------+           +--------+--------+
  |   0    |  >OK
  +--------+
  |   3    |  >Throws Warning
  +--------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have not used SQL much before.

Comment: Keep in mind that some people prefer not to specify or the answer is not always clear-cut. You might be better off including an "unknown" or "unspecified" option.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I understand that there could be several other options for SEX_Values, I just chose to use the two most common for a quick example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE SEX_Values
(
    `CODE` INT NOT NULL,
    `VALUES` VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (`CODE`)   -- !!
);

CREATE TABLE My_Table
(
    SEX INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (SEX) REFERENCES SEX_VALUES(`CODE`)   -- !!
);
```

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is known as a [FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Essentially, it ensures referential integrity - in other words, you can't insert anything that doesn't exist in the referenced table, nor can you delete anything from the referenced table that still exists in the main one.

So, in your case you couldn't insert `Hermaphrodite` into `My_Table` without it being present in `SEX_Values`, nor could you remove `male` from `SEX_Values`, if there were still a `male` in `My_Table`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an [enum type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)?

You can create the table with

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
  sex enum("male", "female") NOT NULL
);
```

That way you can insert like so:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(`sex`) VALUES("male")
```

You have the syntactical advantage of using strings (I think this is a lot more clear than using numeric codes), MySQL will optimize the database as if you were using the codes, and it will enfor.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is to set the datatype of the `sex` column to `bit`, that accepts only 0, 1 or null values ([MSDN ref.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx)).

Set also the `NOT NULL` constraint in the filed definition, in order to exclude NULL values as well.